# except block does not catch the exception in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

my code is like below

```
class Something(models.Model)

    def exception(self)
    try:
       Something.objects.all()
    except Exception():
       raise Exception()
```

called this method from testcases ,its working but i need to raise exception ,it does not catch the exception 
and here is my test case

```
def test_exception(self):
    instance = Something()
    instance.exception()
```

its working fine but i need to raise exception from except block

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. Why are you raising an exception from your catch-block? Also, there are numerous syntax-errors in your example (e.g. missing `:` and bad indentation on `exception`).

Comment: If you using the python unittest framework you probably wanna use the assertRaises(exception) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def exception(self)
    try:
        Something.objects.all()
    except Exception, err:
        #print err.message (if you want)
        raise err
```

This will catch the error and print the exact msg if required.

Comment: I believe you meant `raise err`. You cannot raise `err.message` which is a string.

Answer (score 8):

This line:

```
except Exception():
```

should be:

```
except Exception:
```

Comment: Yes, but of course it shouldn't be, as it's an extremely bad idea to just catch `Exception` - you should catch the actual exceptions you handle, and leave the others to bubble up.

Comment: May I know the reason of the downvote? My reply is technically correct and answers *exactly* the OP question, so I see no justifiable reason for a downvote, see StackOverflow's FAQ. If you want to advise the OP about good Python programming practices, comment the question.

Comment: @nicola You are right. Indeed I upvoted it. It answer the question better than the other answers, which point out the right use, but not why the original example is failing. 
I suspect it should be also `raise Exception` (without parenthesis) or `raise`.
good practice vs bad practice was not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why catch the Exception just to re-raise it?
If you are not doing anything in the except suite except re-raising the exception, then simply do not catch the exception in the first place:

```
@staticmethod
def exception():
    Something.objects.all()
```

---

If you are doing something nontrivial inside the `except` suite, then:

```
def exception(self):
    try:
        Something.objects.all()
    except Exception:
        # do something (with self?)
        raise
```

Then, to test that the `exception` method raises an Exception:

```
def test_exception(self):
    instance = Something()
    self.assertRaises(Exception, instance.exception)
```

This depends on `Something.objects.all()` raising `Exception`.

---

PS. If `exception` does not depend on `self`, then it is best to remove it from the argument list and make `exception` a staticmethod.

PPS. `Exception` is a very broad base exception class. A more specific exception would be more helpful for debugging, and allow other code to catch this specific exception instead of forcing it to handle any possible `Exception`.